# OpenID Connect or OAuth2 - how to get the auth and token endpoints from the issuer metadata endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

i see that we can do a simple HTTPs Get on the metadata endpoint, and read the json values.
currently I am using the google oauth2 library
https://googleapis.dev/java/google-oauth-client/latest/overview-summary.html

i have been reading the javadoc of this library for quiet a while. still i could not figure out how to do this.
i do not want to configure/specify all the three endpoints (authorization, token, userinfo) separately. i rather want to read these endpoints from using something in this api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with that requirement and would also choose a library that works well with metadata.

**CODING APPROACH**

In [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth) I am using a standards based library:

- My IssuerMetadata class gets endpoints
- My authenticator class uses endpoints

**JAVA LIBRARIES I USE**

Personally in Java I like the certified / standards based [Nimbusds open source libraries](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/openid-connect/configuration-request) - their docs are very good also.

**YOUR CHOICE**

You may not need to use Google libraries to call Google, or it may make sense to mix and match sometimes. Personally I try to keep my code based on OAuth 2 and Open Id Connect standard HTTPS messages, rather than on vendor specific libraries

Comment: thx Gary. our j2ee project contains old struts, jsp pages, formbeans, service classes, ibatis dao model, and ibatis xml queries. NO Spring framework. all the pages in the front end are tied to struts 1.2 tag libraries (html, bean, logic, nested, etc.)
i am the significant developer of this application, and after these years, i never knew it would come down to life & death for my job situation on this application.
since Spring is the only framework in Java that is standing good.
one of these days, i must find a way to Springify the application.
now for this requirement, i will use Nimbus

Comment: Good luck :) You should be able to use any standards based library of your choice though - whether Spring or not. It is the underlying standards based behaviour that is important.